# How I can catch "No application is registered as handling this file" in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developing a UI-application with Qt and C++. This program must show list of files which contains given substring. Also I want open file via double click.
I do it like this:

```
bool success = QDesktopServices::openUrl(url);
if (!success) {
    QMessageBox::warning(this, "Opening file", "File could not be opened.", QMessageBox::Ok);
}
```

I know that *path* it's correctly QString with path to file i.e. true that:

```
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)
```

But sometimes I get:

```
gio: No application is registered as handling this file
```

I want catch this error and show message for user via QMessageBox.

Advise how I can do this, please.

Comment: What points out that warning is that there is no application registered in the OS to handle files with that extension.

Comment: The returning Boolean indicates that, what is the Boolean value when you get that warning?